# Simple Quiz and Results in EE?

Tags: ee2

I'd like to see what capabilities EE has for making a quiz with 10 questions, all of which have answers:

Not At All (0)
Not Really (1)
Undecided (2)
Somewhat (3)
Very Much (4)

If the sum of points (in parenthesis) exceeds 20, I want to display some custom message. I'd use Javascript, except I want to also store the results. Any recommendations on the best approach to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you can use 4-EE Quiz Module ( http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/4-eequiz ) which has a built in point and scoring system already while allowing for the users selections to be saved.

Alternatively you could use something like [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) which would allow you to create the questions as fields in Freeform so that the users selections could be stored in the EE DB. You could then use the Javascript that you were planning on using already to calculate the users total and show the messages based upon the users choices.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Actually I'm waiting on the purchasing office to buy 4-EE, and in the meantime, for educational purposes, was wondering if there was another maybe native-EE approach. Freeform looks interesting too, I'll give that a look.

Answer (score 0):

why not use this module. i've done a couple assesssments/quizzes with it: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/4-eequiz